# Vue reactivity issues in component making asynchronous server requests

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

A small amount of context: I have a Vue view called Articles. When the component is mounted to the DOM, I fetch all posts from the database using the axios library (in conjunction with Laravel controllers and API routes). The articles view contains a data property called `active`, which points towards the post that is currently selected. Clicking on a different post in the sidebar updates `active` and subsequently the new post is shown.

Now, every post has many comments, and those comments in turn can be linked to subcomments if you will. However, the mounted lifecycle hook in `Articles.vue` gets invoked only once and when I try to place the server request in `updated()`, everything seemingly works but I'd eventually get a 429 status (too many requests). My guess is that for each comment that is retrieved, the code in `updated()` get's invoked again.

I guess my question is as follows: How can I make `Post.vue` reactive, since right now the mounted lifecycle hook will be invoked only once even when another post is selected.

Here's the code:

**Articles.vue**

```
export default {
        name: "Articles",
        components: {SidebarLink, PageContent, Sidebar, Post, Searchbar, Spinner},
        data() {
            return {
                posts: [],
                active: undefined,
                loading: true
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchPosts();
        },
        methods: {
            async fetchPosts() {
                const response = await this.$http.get('/api/posts');
                this.posts = response.data;
                this.active = this.posts[0];

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                }, 400);
            },
            showPost(post) {
                this.active = post;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Post.vue**

```
export default {
        name: "Post",
        components: {Tag, WennekesComment},
        props: ['post'],
        data() {
            return {
                expanded: true,
                comments: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchComments();
        },
        methods: {
            async fetchComments() {
                let response = await this.$http.get('/api/posts/' + this.post.id + '/comments');
                this.comments = response.data;
            }
        }
    }
```

**WennekesComment.vue**

```
export default {
        name: "WennekesComment",
        props: ['comment'],
        data() {
            return {
                subComments: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchSubcomments();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchSubcomments() {
                let response = this.$http.get('/api/comments/' + this.comment.id).then((result) => {
                    // console.log(result);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

**Template Logic**

`<wennekes-comment v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" :comment="comment"></wennekes-comment>`

`<post v-if="!loading" :post="active" :key="active.id"/>`

Thanks in advance, and my apologies if this question is somewhat unclear, I'm somewhat at a loss.

Regards,

Ryan

**UPDATE**

I think I got it to work. In `Articles.vue`, I have appended a key to the `post` component. I think this is Vue's way of knowing which specific instance of a component to update.

Comment: Can you add the template logic in which you show the  `WennekesComment.vue` component? I think you add it inside `Post.vue`

Comment: I have updated the code! I think I got it to work. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Great make it solved then, other user might find it useful. I see the :key is a common problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it to work. In Articles.vue, I have appended a key to the post component. I think this is Vue's way of knowing which specific instance of a component to update.